# Получение доступа(взлом) к роутеру

Tags: роутер, ddos

Вопрос, наверное, вечный. Конечно я понимаю что я далеко не первый кто это задает, но я до сих пор не до конца понял как все работает. Я обнаружил что есть много способов добиться доступа к вражескому роутеру такими неэффективными сегодня способами как `брутфорс` и `тупой подбор паролей по словарю`, более продвинутые пошли посредством перехвата `хендшейков` и подбора совпадений уже на локальном устройстве, что в сотни или даже тысячи раз быстрее, но менее надежно, но ведь это далеко не самый выгодный вариант. Наиболее продвинутые хакеры явно могут как-то провести `DDoS` атаку на роутер, что назвали, как я прочитал, `DNS Amplification`, но я не нашел как такие атаки проводят. Что они используют для проведения таких атак, подробный мануал на их проведение, подробный мануал по защите от них..

Я, вероятно, не прав в чем-то, тогда подскажите какие варианты атак на роутер могут быть произведены еще и ресурс на подробности в придачу.

И еще, я не уверен что обратился на тот ресурс сети stackoverflow, если это так - не вините сильно, я не нашел более правильного за тематикой.

Comment: Более подходящим для этой темы был бы http://serverfault.com/, но его пока еще нет на русском.

Comment: @WalterNuss: надеюсь, и не будет. Англоязычные сайты не раз пожалели о разделении. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендую на полноту, но добавлю к этому списку уязвимости в ПО роутера (несколько примеров можно видеть, например, в статье ["Как взламывали и защищали сети в 2014 году"](http://www.ptsecurity.ru/ics/5.03.2015_webinar.pdf) от Positive Technologies (PT)), а также использование [бэкдоров](http://habrahabr.ru/post/183314/) (тоже приведена ссылка как пример, ибо "их есть" почти у каждого производителя). Вот в этой статье от PT ["СТАТИСТИКА УЯЗВИМОСТЕЙ КОРПОРАТИВНЫХ ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫХ СИСТЕМ 2014"](http://www.ptsecurity.ru/download/PT_Corporate_vulnerability_2015_rus.pdf) можно встретить такие векторы атак, как недостатки конфигурации SSL. Пересказывать содержание ссылок не считаю целесообразным, поскольку назвал направления, а технических деталей там очень много.

Припоминается еще атака в виде посылки на роутер (и другие устройства) специально сформированного пакета с инженерной информацией, дающей полный доступ к устройству, но к сожалению не вспомню названия (а детали тем более, т.к. специфичны для каждого производителя).

Можно вспомнить еще такие детские болезни, как логины и пароли в админке по умолчанию, но это, скорее, подмножество словарных паролей.

Answer (score 3):

Тема, которую Вы обозначили в вопросе, очень обширная и в двух словах на вопрос не ответишь. Вариантов атак и взломов очень-очень много. Опишу немного.

**Брутфорс** - подбор пароля. Несмотря на малую эффективность применяется часто. Но только не тупой брутфорс по всем наборам символов, а подбор по словарю. Человеку проще запомнить что-то осмысленное, чем случайный набор, поэтому атака по словарю часто приводит к успеху.

**Перехват handshake** - более продвинутая тактика. Применяется в беспроводных сетях. Атакующий посылает клиенту от имени точки пакет с командой разрыва соединения, а затем ловит пакеты клиента с его повтороной авторизацией на точке. В них содержатся данные авторизации, которые можно попытаться расшифровать.

**DDoS** - не взлом, а атака типа *отказ в обслуживании*. В случае домашнего роутера цель такой атаки - либо загрузить машинку так, чтобы она всю свою мощность тратила на обработку "левых" запросов и, соответственно, для легитимных клиентов мало что оставалось, либо забить канал, чтобы легитимные клиенты не могли протолкнуться.

*DNS Amplification* - это один из видов DDoS-атак, в которых относительно небольшой трафик, направляемый на неправильно сконфигурированные DNS-сервера, превращается в очень большой, направленный на жертву. Используется подмена IP-адреса отправителя запроса на IP-адрес жертвы.

Для DDoS нужно одно - бот-сеть.

Относительно DoS и DDoS рекомендую посмотреть [отличную лекцию](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=et7eTx0-IGg) Артёма Гавриченкова - технического директора компании QRator.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, даже левому было интересно:)

Comment: Я знаю что значат все эти определения, хотя благодарю за последнее, на счет него я был не в курсе... Но я спросил что эффективнее, что чаще употребляется профессионалами и как это работает.

Comment: @Levelleor Я не профессионал во взломе. И не профессионал в защите. Написал что знаю. ;)